# Dynamic Interactions on a VR Video

Tags: image, unity-game-engine, virtual-reality, google-vision

We are trying to build a VR app using Unity3D. Basically the objective is when we feed in a VR video. User should be able to gaze at some moving object and get information about that moving object in VR. 
Manually It can done in Unitym by going frame to frame and plot the movement of object and map the interactions to it.
But what about automatically, If I feed in vertices of the polygonal area around that object to Unity3D, can it automatically generate interactions based on my logic. If yes then how?

Comment: Could you provide more details? What do you mean by a "VR Video"? Did you mean showing a 2D video in a VR setting, a 360-degrees video, or another specific types of videos? When you said "going frame to frame", did you mean to move objects like (Transform.translate()), or literally manually placing objects in scenes and creating N scenes to create N-frames? Does "vertices of the polygonal area" mean the vertices of objects that appear in your video?

Comment: Hi tarun did you find any solution?

Comment: @Matthias any solution available?